# HTML/CSS: table rows height and border color

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the border color in the table in this page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/print.html

I've added an empty row and specified a height to add some vertical space before the table bottom row.

However I cannot change the border color of this row. it is always gray. All the css code is inline.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 <tr style="height: 60px;"></tr>
```

To

```
 <tr style="height: 60px;"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Edit it looks like there are just two columns so i've changed the answer to reflect that.

Comment: cells can't be empty so at least one space should be added so add &nbsp; to fix the blank cell

Comment: @KoolKabin Wouldn't `empty-cells: show;` suffice? (but then `height` should be defined for `td` instead of `tr` i guess)

Comment: @cji - tested that in FF4 Beta and that works as well, but only if you add the `td`

Answer (score 0):

Add your border style to the line and that should work.

```
<tr style="height: 60px;"></tr>
```

Cheers.

Comment: no it doesn't, that's why i posted this question. Or I'm doing it wrongly... <tr style="height: 60px; border:1px solid black;"></tr> ?